# how to change view's vairable in js of rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

how to change view's variable value in javascript. I mean when i select April from dropdown table will show only April's data and current table data will disappear and refreshed. How can i do it? Help me

My JS

```
:javascript
    var updateMonth = function(){
        var month_id = $("#select_other_month").val();
        console.log(month_id)
    }
```

here is my select tag (dropdown)

```
%select{:name => "options", :id=>"select_other_month",:onchange=>"updateMonth()"}
            %option.placeholder{:disabled => "", :selected => "", :value => ""} see other months
            %option{:value => "0"} this month
            -a=@this_month - 1.month
            %option{:value => "5"}=a.strftime('%Y-%m')
            -b=@this_month - 2.month
            %option{:value => "4"}=b.strftime('%Y-%m')
            -c=@this_month - 3.month
            %option{:value => "3"}=c.strftime('%Y-%m')
            -d=@this_month - 4.month
            %option{:value => "2"}=d.strftime('%Y-%m')
            -e=@this_month - 5.month
            %option{:value => "1"}=e.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

and my table looks like this

```
.table{:id=>"time_table"}
        %table{:border=>"1"}
            %thead
                %tr
                    %th No
                    %th Name
                    -(@xmonth.at_beginning_of_month..@xmonth.at_end_of_month).each do |day|
                        -if (day.saturday? || day.sunday?)==false
                            %th=day.strftime("%d")
                    %th Total days
                    %th Total time
```

I want change my @xmonth vairable from JS

Note: @this_month = Date.today

Comment: You want to fetch fresh data from server and populate?

Comment: Yes i am. What should i do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var updateMonth = function(){
  var month_id = $("#select_other_month").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/your_controller/its_method', //make sure to add this path to routes file
    data: {
      month_id: month_id
    },
    success: function(response){
      $("#target_area").html(response);
    },
    error: function(error_res){
      console.log(error_res);
    }
  });
}
```

In your view file add an id, so we can replace its content with the new response we get

```
%thead{:id => "target_area"}
  %tr
    %th No
    %th Name
    ...
```

In your controller

```
class YourController
   def your_method
     month_id = params[:month_id]
     #update your @xmonth by month_id
     #your new information should be inside @xmonth object
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html {render partial: 'your_controller/your_method/your_partial.haml.erb' }
     end
   end
end
```

Create your partial file `_your_partial.haml.erb` with the content that needs to be replaced

```
%tr
  %th No
  %th Name
  -(@xmonth.at_beginning_of_month..@xmonth.at_end_of_month).each do |day|
    -if (day.saturday? || day.sunday?)==false
  %th=day.strftime("%d")
  %th Total days
  %th Total time
```

The partial's content will be replaced in your view with the content of `#target_area` when you get a success response. See the updateMonth function.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for answer my question. But i got problem with your advice. The error message is on my question.

Comment: @NeoTeo While rendering the partial inside `format.html` do not use `_` as it will automatically add it for you.

Comment: Awesome! Sorry if I wrote haml wrong anywhere. Not using haml.

Comment: It's ok no problem. Thank you :)